# XCode - Validate Built Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-settings

In my XCode project, I have 4 different Build Configurations: Production, Development, Staging, and Staging2.

In my Build Settings, I noticed `Validate Built Product` is set to No for all configurations. If I switch them to Yes, I then get a warning each time I try to build:

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

I'm still able to build on to the phone and create Archives though.

At least for production, I'd like to turn `Validate Built Project` to Yes, but I don't want to see that error each time.

How can I make codesign happy?

**Note**: I recently upgraded to XCode 4.6, reinstalled the command line tools, and updated my project settings when XCode prompted me to do so. I confirmed that I had Production set to Yes all along, which tells me something with this upgrade is causing this error.

Also, I've read [this support doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32) pretty thoroughly, followed all the steps, and it seems as though everything was correct to begin with.

Comment: Then what is wrong with your build

Comment: There are no other errors or warnings, and the app still builds to the phone and simulator fine and Archives. Looks like there's nothing wrong with the my build. But I guess that's what I'm asking.